# textwrangler: how can I run without opening files?

Tags: macos, textwrangler

TextWrangler has always worked great, but now it's hanging everytime I open it.

I suspect one of the files it's trying to open causes a problem.

Is there a way to run it without opening any files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TextWrangler preferences are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/` in:

- the file `com.barebones.textwrangler.plist`
- the files in the directory `com.barebones.textwrangler.PreferenceData`

I don't know which of the files contains the open documents. Move the files/folder to your desktop and try starting it, then put them back one after another to find the source of your problem.

Comment: It looks like it was com.barebones.textwrangler.PreferenceData/Saved Application State.appstate

Answer (score 7):

You can press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while launching TextWrangler to suppress all normal startup actions, including reopening files.

Comment: This still works as of Dec 31, 2014 in BBEdit 11.0.2. Great tip.

Answer (score 2):

mv ~/Library/TextWrangler/Saved Application State-023BCD4D-6979-5237-893B-7DE068E1516A.appstate Saved Application State-023BCD4D-6979-5237-893B-7DE068E1516A.appstate_bkp

This resolved issue for me.

Note that the state id will be different in your m/c

Answer (score -1):

Go to TextWrangler > Preferences > Application and uncheck the box that says "Reopen documents that were open last quit"[image]

Comment: Sorry, this wouldn't have worked: I couldn't do anything in TextWrangler at all -- it hung immediately upon opening. Also I want it to reopen documents that were open at last quit.

Comment: What did work then?  I was merely addressing the question asked "Is there a way to run it without opening any files?"

Comment: Deleting the preference file responsible for restoring documents on opening worked. @Jason's problem was he couldn't open the editor because of this, so there was no way to get into its preferences dialog.